# SSL peer shut down incorrectly: Getting error in Android Studiio, while building build.gradle of libGDX

Tags: java, android, maven, ssl, libgdx

I am novice to libGDX, and while setting it for android studio, I encountered following issue:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'FirstGame'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not download robovm-dist-compiler.jar (org.robovm:robovm-dist-compiler:1.12.0)
  >   Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/robovm/robovm-dist-compiler/1.12.0/robovm-dist-compiler-1.12.0.jar'.
  >   SSL peer shut down incorrectly
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

  BUILD FAILED

  Total time: 3.93 secs

I followed the following steps:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle

But, getting the error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean]
```

Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/robovm/robovm-dist-compiler/1.12.0/robovm-dist-compiler-1.12.0.jar
Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'FirstGame'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not download robovm-dist-compiler.jar (org.robovm:robovm-dist-compiler:1.12.0)
>   Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/robovm/robovm-dist-compiler/1.12.0/robovm-dist-compiler-1.12.0.jar'.
>   SSL peer shut down incorrectly
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 3.93 secs
>   Information:1 error
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

Comment: Did you tried this Post? Did it help? stackoverflow.com/questions/36809652/ssl-peer-shut-down-incorrectly-getting-error-in-android-studiio-while-building?rq=1

Comment: I was working on it a few months earlier. Nothing helped me at all. Will try the link.

Comment: Did you figure out the issue?  I am running into the same thing myself when building on a Docker image.  When I run locally it seems to work just fine.